# Linear independence of powers

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $a=2^{1/n}$. Prove that $a, a^2, a^3,...,a^{n-1}$ are linearly independent (in Q). I tried solving it by assuming that $a^x$ is a linear combination of the others (e.g. $a^x=p/q(a^y+a^z+...)$) and then raising to the n-th power, but I realised that I can't get rid of irrational numbers in the equality, so I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a$ is a root of $x^n-2$, which is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion.

Therefore, $x^n-2$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb Q$.

This implies that $a$ is not a root of any polynomial of degree less than $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$.

This is just another way to say that  $1,a, a^2, a^3,\dots,a^{n-1}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, because any nontrivial linear relation
$$
c_0 \cdot 1+c_1 \cdot a+c_2 \cdot a^2+\cdots+c_{n-1}  \cdot a^{n-1} = 0
$$
gives a polynomial of degree less than $n$ having $a$ as root.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last line? Why does this mean that they are independent?

Comment: @Nesa, see my edited answer.