# Linearly independent set in $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The set $$\left\{\sqrt[2^n]{2},\quad n\in\mathbb N\right\}\subset\mathbb R$$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

Is there an easy or elementary way to see this? I.e., why does the equation $\alpha_1 2^{2^{-i_1}}+\cdots +\alpha_N 2^{2^{-i_N}}=0$ not have a non-trivial solution in $\alpha_i\in\mathbb Q$ for any choice of $N\in\mathbb N$ and $i_1,\dots,i_N\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Why are there $i_k$ in your equation? Shouldn't these be just $k$?

Comment: They stand for an arbitrary choice of indices since they don't necessarily need to be $1, ..., N$

Comment: @BillO'Haran An infinite set of vectors in some linear space is lin. independent iff every finite subset is lin. independent. As the OP commented above, the finite subset doesn't have to have successive indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, for each $N \in \mathbb N$, the set $\left\{\sqrt[2^n]{2} : n=0,\dots,N\right\}$ is linearly independent because $X^{2^N}-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ due to Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787792/589