# Why the field extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I know the extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ is not finite, as $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable whereas $\mathbb{C}$ is not.

However, how should I prove that the field extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated?

Comment: If it were, then it would be countable as well.

Comment: It seems you've already proved it: if $F$ is finitely generated over $E$ and $E$ is countable, then $F$ is countable. What more are you looking for?

Comment: @OrShahar For me, the extension $L/K$ is finitely generated if there exist $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in L$ such that $L=K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$.

Comment: I think it's due to the fact that there exist infintly many algebraic independent transcendental numbers in $\Bbb{C}$ (I can't find a proof rith know, it's just an idea)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996903/linearly-independent-set-in-mathbb-r-over-mathbb-q/3996925#3996925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just need to show that if $K$ is a field with countable (infinite) cardinality, then any countably generated field $L$ over $K$ is also countable. By induction, it's sufficient to show any simple extension $K(\alpha)$ is countable. And indeed $$K(\alpha)=\cup_{n=1}^\infty \{ \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\alpha^i}{\sum_{i=0}^n b_i\alpha^i} | a_i, b_i\in K, \sum_{i=0}^n b_i\alpha^i\not=0\}$$

Note that the cardinality of $\{ \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\alpha^i}{\sum_{i=0}^n b_i\alpha^i} | a_i, b_i\in K, \sum_{i=0}^n b_i\alpha^i\not=0\}$ won't exceed $|K|^{2n}$, hence must be countable as well.

So just to recognize there aren't so many polynomials (or fractions), which was first known to Cantor who proved there exist transcendental numbers this way without exhibiting a single example.