# Show that the dimension of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (algebraic numbers) as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, vector-spaces, algebraic-number-theory

How can you prove that the dimension of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (algebraic numbers) as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite?

I thought about showing that the vectors
$$
\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}, \ldots, \sqrt{p_n}
$$
for arbitrary $n$ are linearly independent where $p_n$ denotes the $n$-th prime number. That means I would have to show that if
$$
q_1 \sqrt{2} + q_2 \sqrt{3} + \ldots + q_n \sqrt{p_n} = 0
$$
for rational $q_1,\ldots,q_n$ then $q_1=\ldots=q_n=0$. W.l.o.g. we can even assume that $q_1,\ldots,q_n$ are integers.

Is there a more elegant way to prove this?

Comment: Well, all you need is to prove that there is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ with arbitrarily high degree.

Comment: Prove that $x^n-2$ Is irreducible

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787751/linear-independence-of-powers/1787792#1787792

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be any prime number. Consider a polynimial $Q_n (x) =x^n- p$ it is irreducible over rationals by Einsenstein  criterion.
Hence $[\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[n]{2}]:\mathbb{Q}] =n$ but $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[n]{2}]\subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ for all $\in\mathbb{N}.$ Therefore $\mbox{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}} (\overline{\mathbb{Q} })=\infty.$

Comment: I haven't learned about the Eisenstein criterion but I think the rational root theorem might be sufficient. The only rational roots of the monic polynomial $Q_n$ are integers by the rational root theorem. But no integer to the power of $n>1$ is a prime number (the case $n=1$ is trivial) which means that $Q_n$ has no rational roots and is therefore irreducible over the rationals.
The argument now is: Since $x^n-2$ is irreducible the number $\alpha = \sqrt[n]{2}$ has degree $n$. Thus $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha ^{n-1}$ are all linearly independent. Is this correct?

Comment: Tobias, it is not true, that a polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, if it has no rational roots. Consider $f(x)=(x^2+1)^2$, which is reducible. And if you haven't looked up Eisenstein so far, it is a good opportunity now.